# convert char* to structure in c++

Tags: c++, struct, reinterpret-cast

I have the following structure

```
struct record{
RType m_rectype;
char m_recordname[11];
char m_recordNo;
char m_record_date[6];
}
```

and I have a following line of char* type

```
line = "1Netherlands3240382"
```

How can I covert this line into the structure. Performance is important as I have a huge data to process.

I have used reinterpret_cast but the array elements of the struct or not null terminated.

```
record r = reinterpret_cast<const record* >(line)
```

Edit: the final results should be as following

```
r.m_rectype = "1"
r.m_recordname = "Netherlands"
r.m_recordNo = "3"
r.m_record_date = "240382"
```

but I am getting instead the following

```
r.m_rectype = "1"
r.m_recordname = "Netherlands3240382"
r.m_recordNo = "3"
r.m_record_date = "240382"
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to convert it? What should be the values of the members after the conversion? Btw `reinterpret_cast` is not the right way

Comment: Are you sure about that structure? The pointers (and arrays of pointers) look wrong compared to your sample data.

Comment: Are you sure you want `char*[11]`, and not `char[11]`? Anyway `Netherlands` has 11 characters, so you'd need at least 12 if you wanted it to be null-terminated.

Comment: Have you tried the simplest possible approach that could work (ie pointer manipulation and the occasional `strncpy` into a pre-allocated memory arena? Computers are plenty fast. Or, if you can convince the other side to switch to protocol buffers, ...

Comment: ah sorry, I have corrected the structure and included the desired output, can you please look into it now? thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's not `char m_recordNo;` ? otherwise you are trying to get (at least) 23 bytes of data out of 19 bytes of input, and you end up with most likely an invalid pointer value.

Comment: @Caleth yes, you are right. corrected

Comment: What if instead of "Netherlands" you have "Papua-New Guinea" or "Italy"?

Comment: For the output of `r.m_recordname = "Netherlands3240382"`, are you creating it by using `printf("r.m_recordname = \"%11.11s\"", r.m_recordname);'`?

Comment: @BogdanDoicin this is an example string. the file I am dealing with has fixed line length of 200 bytes with positions defined for each entry according to international standard. and some how I have to read those bytes from the file and convert that stream into a structure. my actual structure contains more than 30 variables. Here I put a small struct for an example. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I have used reinterpret_cast

`reinterpret_cast` cannot be used for this. Your usage has undefined behaviour. The following would be well defined:

```
record r; // create a record object
std::memcpy(&r, line, sizeof r);
```

Caveats:

- The strings are not null terminated!
- `sizeof(RType)` must be 1
- The input buffer must not be shorter than `sizeof r`.

---

> but I am getting instead the following
>
> ```
> r.m_recordname = "Netherlands3240382"
> ```

`Netherlands3240382` does not fit inside the member `m_recordname`, and therefore that cannot possibly be the state of the object. The issue must be in the way the output is generated. My suspicion is that the string is being treated as if it were null-terminated, despite it not being so.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `RType` is a `char` backed enum type (or an alias for some `char` type), you *can* `memcpy` your input into a `record` object. You may also be able to trick your compiler into doing what you intend with the `reinterpret_cast`.

The problem you are experience however, sounds like you are *observing* the values in this `record` object via functions that assume null terminated strings. You should instead use functions that accept a length.

```
printf("r.m_rectype = \"%d\"", r.m_rectype);
printf("r.m_recordname = \"%11.11s\"", r.m_recordname);
printf("r.m_recordNo = \"%d\"", r.m_recordNo);
printf("r.m_record_date = \"%6.6s\"", r.m_record_date);
```

Comment: I need not to print it but to actually have it in the structure correct.

Comment: @Fawad You can't fit 12 `char`s into a `char[11]`. Your example is (probably) correct, the tool you are using to observe its value is just assuming there will be a null terminator.

Comment: yes, true but if I increase the size to char[12] it is not going to help as it would get the next byte instead. can there be another way other than using reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @Fawad You **don't need** a null at the end of a `char[11]`. Just don't pass it to anything expecting a null-terminated string

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking the Standard gives no guarantees about padding between elements of a `struct`, other than that there will be no padding at the beginning. So, even though your *particular* struct is unlikely to have padding - being (I assume) all character types, to be safe, you can do something like this:

```
template<typename Pod>
char const* pod_copy(char const* p, Pod& pod)
{
    static_assert(std::is_pod_v<Pod>, "Must be Plain Old Data type");

    std::copy(p, p + sizeof(pod), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pod));
    return p + sizeof(pod);
}

struct record{
    RType m_rectype;
    char m_recordname[11];
    char m_recordNo;
    char m_record_date[6];
};

int main()
{
    record r;

    auto line = "1Netherlands3240382";

    auto p = line;

    p = pod_copy(p, r.m_rectype);
    p = pod_copy(p, r.m_recordname);
    p = pod_copy(p, r.m_recordNo);
    p = pod_copy(p, r.m_record_date);

    // .. rest of program
}
```

This should be very quick because `pos_copy` should inline well.